# Increment number in a URL

Tags: jquery

I have a URL stored in a variable and would like to increment the number at the end of the image name by 1 when a user clicks,

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.next', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = "http://www-url.com/img/436x768/look1.png";

});
```

How could I go about this? thanks.

Comment: do you want the page to go to the new url? or just change it.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221698/increment-value-within-a-url-in-order-to-parse-data-from-attributes-that-are-pag

Comment: just change that variable, thanks

Comment: do you want this number to be preserved between page refreshes?

Comment: i++;  "look"+i+".png";

Answer (score 4):

```
var counter=0 // global variable

$(document).on('click', 'a.next', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++; // add 1 to variable
    var URL = "http://www-url.com/img/436x768/look"+counter+".png";

});
```